# Error when install PHP with brew in OS Monterey

Tags: php, homebrew, macos-monterey

I got php is deleted in OS Monterey, so I try to install it via Homebrew

I already install Homebrew, update tap to shivammathur/php and use this command

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

but I got this response code

```
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
Warning: No available formula with the name "httpd" (dependency of shivammathur/php/php@7.4).
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

When I check brew version with `brew --version` I got this info

```
Homebrew 3.3.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (no Git repository)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 5c43c2133d; last commit 2021-11-06)
```

is that **no Git repository** issue related with why I cant install php in my device? How to solve this issue

**I need this to install composer and install Laravel,** so install XAMPP I think is not clear solution right now

Thankyou

Comment: This question is more likely to get an answer on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: If you are facing any problem with installing a package using Brew, please use the proper issue tracker, like https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php/issues

Answer (score 5):

I recently had this exact problem and tried

```
brew tap homebrew/core
```

However, it didn't work. This did work for me

```
rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
brew tap homebrew/core
brew install php
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As the output of `brew --version` says `homebrew-core` repository is missing, that is why brew is not able to find `httpd`.

```
Homebrew/homebrew-core (no Git repository)
```

Please tap the core repository and try again.

```
brew tap homebrew/core
```

Answer (score 0):

Try write this in terminal:
git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout master

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it